# Running GamingAnywhere from Shell scripting in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, games

I'm trying to run game on gamingAnywhere "Event-Driven Server" by shell scripting at startup.
I tried lots of ways but not really working.

1.

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin -e './ga-server-event-driven config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf'
```

but it couldn't run the game.

2.

```
/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/ga-server-event-driven /Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf
```

It runs the game but doesn't runs all the modules e.g ga-hook-sdk.so

3.

I tried pipping too but didn't worked either.

I want to run the game with all modules. I hope the 1st method can help but child process exited with code 0. doesn't work.

I'm new to this shell scripting. So help me please.

Comment: Use this `/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/ga-server-event-driven /Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf` to run it in the first option!

Comment: It doesn't work  gives "child process exited normally with status 0". Game doesn't run.